# How to make Apple Mail client open messages on my secondary display?

Tags: apple-mail

Been looking high & low and while I've found many people asking the exact opposite question, I can't seem to solve this one.

I have dual monitors and I'm running Lion 10.7.4, and I want to run Apple Mail on my "secondary" display.  But no matter what I do, any time I open a message (I prefer the "classic layout") it always opens on the "primary" display, which I'm trying to prevent.

How can I force Apple Mail to only open messages on the same display where the main mail viewer is, which is my secondary display?

Comment: Do any of the answers here help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-move-a-window-from-one-monitor-to-another  Most of them seem to require keyboard shortcuts, no automatic moving...

Comment: Appreciate the link, but unfortunately no... that's a completely different topic.  I can already manually (via shortcuts) move windows between monitors.  I just want Mail to default to opening messages on the same monitor where its main window lives (my secondary one).  For the time being I'm resigned to defining a single Desktop for mail, and having the main window on one screen, and messages opening on the other.  Messy but... guess I'll have to live with it!